# how to add a cetificate to httpweb request using X509Certificate2

Tags: c#

Need your help to find a better way to add a certificate while sending a web request. To be more specific i am doing a project were i need to send a request to the broker and broker has asked to send a certificate information in every request. So i got the certificate file named ch1vw-ub004477.pfx which is password protected and i have placed this file in my bin folder. i have added the below code and it works.But i wanted to know is there any better way. Instead of placing the certificate in bin folder can i pick the certificate from windows machine or something like that.

```
 HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(brokerprovidedurl);
 X509Certificate2 oCert = new X509Certificate2(sslpath, sslcertificatepassword, 
 X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);
 request.ClientCertificates.Add(oCert);
```

Comment: You could try https://sirarsalih.com/2018/01/30/fetching-an-installed-certificate-programmatically-from-the-windows-local-machine-store/ . What did you search for so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. I think you should pick it up from the store. I guess its better and safer. There is the connection User Windows account -> Store. I can place a certificate on the store for everybody that uses the machine or just for my account which have privileges.

Here's an example in code. This code was tested several times and it is solid.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Gets the certificate from store.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="certificateStoreName">The certificate store name.</param>
    /// <param name="certificateStoreLocation">The certificate store location.</param>
    /// <param name="certificateSearchType">The certificate search type.</param>
    /// <param name="searchValue">The certificate search value.</param>
    /// <param name="validOnly">The valid only value.</param>
    /// <returns>The store certificate.</returns>
    public static X509Certificate2 GetClientCertificate(StoreName certificateStoreName, StoreLocation certificateStoreLocation, X509FindType certificateSearchType, string searchValue, bool validOnly)
    {
        X509Store store = new X509Store(certificateStoreName, certificateStoreLocation);
        store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly | OpenFlags.OpenExistingOnly);
        X509Certificate2 certificate;

        try
        {
            X509Certificate2Collection certificate2Collection = store.Certificates.Find(certificateSearchType, searchValue, false);

            if (certificate2Collection.Count == 0)
            {
                throw new Exception(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "No certificate found. ({0})", searchValue));
            }

            if (validOnly)
            {
                var now = DateTime.Now;
                certificate = certificate2Collection.Cast<X509Certificate2>()
                    .Where(x => x.NotAfter > now && x.NotBefore < now)
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.NotAfter)
                    .FirstOrDefault();

                if (certificate == null)
                {
                    throw new InvalidOperationException(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "GetClientCertificate -> No valid certificate found. ({0})", searchValue));
                }
            }
            else
            {
                certificate = certificate2Collection[0];
            }
        }
        finally
        {
            store.Close();
        }

        return certificate;
    }
```

Comment: thanks John777. but my certificate is password protected.. if i use the above code how do i add password ? Please help